# working with nodeList "childNodes" of element.Why isn't the container2 being removed?

Tags: javascript, removechild, nodelist

I have the following code and I am trying to remove dynamically all the "container" elements from an element `supercontainer` dynamically.Since nodeList is live the following code should remove the `container1` as well as `container2` but it isn't.Can any one tell why?how do I improve this code so as to dynamically remove all childNodes?

```
<html><body></body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var supercontainer=document.createElement("div");
var container2=document.createElement("div");
var container1=document.createElement("div");
var b=document.createElement("div");
var c=document.createElement("div");
var d=document.createElement("div");
b.appendChild(document.createTextNode("book1"));
c.appendChild(document.createTextNode("book2"));
d.appendChild(document.createTextNode("book3"));
container1.appendChild(b);
container1.appendChild(c);
container1.appendChild(d);
container2.appendChild(document.createTextNode("i am container2"));
supercontainer.appendChild(container1);
supercontainer.appendChild(container2);
document.body.appendChild(supercontainer);
function removeContainers(){
var j=0;
for(i=0;i<supercontainer.childNodes.length;i++){
        supercontainer.removeChild(supercontainer.childNodes[j]);
    }
}
removeContainers();
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your loop,

1. i = 0; then nodes.length is 2
2. first item is removed then i becomes 1 and length becomes 1
3. the loop terminating condition fails

The solution is to keep the loop count in a separate counter variable like `length`

Use

```
function removeContainers(){
    var j=0, len = supercontainer.childNodes.length;
    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
        supercontainer.removeChild(supercontainer.childNodes[j]);
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/B8dwT/)

Comment: Oh thank you man you got it working for me,I wasn't realizing that every time the length will also get changed

Comment: @RomanticElectron glad it was of help, it is a common mistake

Answer (score 0):

Because your loop is missing elements.

In the first iteration, you remove the element that is first in the `NodeList`. As you said, `NodeList`'s are live, so this element is removed from the `NodeList` you're iterating over as well. This shifts the element that *was* `[1]`'st to `[0]`th.

The loop then increments `i` to `[1]`, so you ignore the element that *is now 0* in the list.

Instead;

```
while (supercontainer.childNodes.length) {
    supercontainer.removeChild(supercontainer.childNodes[0]);
}
```